# Prove limit of a piecewise function without jump discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

Given  \begin{cases} 
      x & x\leq 0 \\
      x^2 & x > 0 \\ 
   \end{cases}

I need to prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x) = 0$. Since this is a piecewise function, how can I apply the definition of the limit for function to prove this statement?

Comment: The limit exists iff the right-hand side and left-hand side limits exist and are equal (if you want, you can try to prove this using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit.)

Comment: Do you mean I need to apply the definition of limit for both left hand and right hand side functions?

Comment: show $\lim_{x -> 0^{-}}f(x) = f(0) = \lim_{x -> 0^{+}}f(x) $

Comment: See [the fact from these Calc I notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/OneSidedLimits.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of negative numbers converging to zero. Choose $N$ so that $|X_N-0|<\varepsilon,$ then $|f(x_N)-0|<\varepsilon$ for $n\geqslant N$, so that $\lim_{x\uparrow 0}=f(x)=0$.

The argument for $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}=f(x)$ is analogous, but we must take care with the $x^2$. Instead let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers converging to zero, and choose $N$ so that $|X_N-0|<\varepsilon^2$. Then for $n\geqslant N$ we have $|f(X_N)-0|=|f(X_N)|=|x^2|<\varepsilon^2$, which implies that $|x|<\varepsilon$, and we are done.